# Fragment recreated after activity killed on low memory

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, low-memory

I have an `Activity` with a `ViewPager` inside. When activity created a `asyncTask` is executed and when task is finished a `Fragment` is created using the result data.(Important note: without this data `Fragment` create view will crash because its explictly needs that data)

Now after `Fragment` is created i go back to home screen, open another app and so on and create a low memory situation. My `Activity` is killed because of the low memory.

Now i open task manager and click my app again.

Android tries to bring everything back on the screen. Since all the `Activity` is killed data is also lost but it still tries to recreate the fragment although there is no data and my app crashes.

What can I do?... I have two solution (well at least theoritical solutions)

1. prevent activity restart on resume (how can i do that????)
2. prevent fragment create view to use data unless it exists

Well i did implement the second solution. So app doesnt crash in the beginning because "no data exist" is handeld. BUT i realised that ViewPager also disconnected from the fragments because well activity was killed. So i can not reach the fragment back from the activity.

Answer (score 4):

And years after... Having the same kind of problem, a brutal solution is to set the savedInstanceSate to null before calling super :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState = null;
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation on why this works?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of executing the Async task onCreate do it in the onResume to be called whenever your app is back on top

As for the fragment, create it or call it in the onPostExecute of your Async task to insure data is loaded. ( if you call is else where upon request (like on button click) then condition its calling by a boolean variable and set this variable to false in the onResume and set it to true in the onPostExecute of your Async task)

one more thing: you might want to show a progress dialog with (cancelable = false) in your Async task to insure data integrity and to prevent the user from navigating your pager unless data is fully loaded,
- Show the progress dialog in the onPreExecute and (diss miss) it in the onPostExecute

-- Hope this help :)

Comment: Well i already create my fragment in the onPostExecute. But when activity is killed on low memory and application brought to front on request, android tries to recreate the fragment by itself without any call... thats when the app crashes..

Comment: Sorry I cant think of any thing now but a quick work around is to enclose your fragment creation code with a try catch, and for you the catch will be called when your scenario of low memory happen, thus inside the catch execute your Async task. Let me know if this works, Good luck

Comment: There is another problem though... in my activity i use viewpager. I create two fragments and attach the to the view pager and time to time calling some methods from this fragments in my activity.. afer the app is killed on low memory and recreated fragments are there but no connection with the viewpager somehome.. i can not call MyFragment.mymethod().. it says MyFragment is null

Comment: I really cant understand this cycle behavior, if you revise the activity life cycle you can clearly see that killing an app due to memory need, will cause the app to fully restarting the cycle starting from onCreate. Just like a fresh launch of the app. This is strange and as for me I am out of ideas. Someone with more experience might be more helpfull than me :/

Comment: Yeah... thats what i thought too... how come not everything fires in the order they supposed to be fired!!!

Comment: I also can not debug truely because my debugger is disconnecting wenn android kills the activity on low memory

Answer (score 0):

At the Activity, get Fragment in ViewPager by this code

```
fragment = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("android:switcher:" + R.id.rewards_viewpager + ":"+position);
```

Then

```
fragment.doSomething();
```